# how to push values from listObjects to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an array for example  named yourArray.  `var yourArray = [];`  When I get object names with listObjects from s3, I want to push this object names to the array.

```
var params ={
     Bucket: 'exBucket',
     Prefix: 'somePrefix'
};

s3.listObjects(params, function(Err, Data){
    if(!Err){
      for (var i = 0; i < Data.Contents.length; i++){
         console.log('Listed: ', Data.Contents[i].Key);
         yourArray.push(Data.Contents[i].Key);
      }
    };
});
```

Here, `console.log('Listed: ', Data.Contents[i].Key);` gives me the all names. But `yourArray.push(Data.Contents[i].Key);` doesnt push the names and array is still empty. Where is the mistake ?

Comment: I suspect `listObjects` is asynchronous, and you are checking the contents of `yourArray` before the `listObjects` has completed

Comment: yes @JaromandaX this process is in an asynchronious modul named "async". so, what should I do with yourArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jaromanda X said, `listObjects` is asynchronous and your function is trying to put the value in the array before the object is completed.

For dealing with such S3 object, I would recommand using Bluebird promise

https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-promised